# Ansible multiple variable contains multiple values

Tags: bash, variables, ansible

i have some ansible task below :

```
    - name: counting object from json
     shell: >
      jq '.results[].stdout_lines | length' backup/{{ inventory_hostname }}_rsl.json | wc -l
     register: jsondata
   - name: counting object converting
     shell: >
      seq 0 {{ jsondata.stdout|int - 1 }} | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs | sed 's/[[:space:]]/,/g'
     register: seq
   - name: get interface
     shell: >
      cat backup/{{ inventory_hostname }}_{{ item }}_rsl_result_nows.json | cut -d, -f1
     register: interface
     with_items:
      - "{{ seq.stdout.split(',') | list }}"
   - name: get rsl value
     shell: >
      cat backup/{{ inventory_hostname }}_{{ item }}_rsl_result_nows.json | cut -d, -f2-
     register: rslvalue
     with_items:
      - "{{ seq.stdout.split(',') | list }}"
   - name: post to DB via curl
     shell: >
      curl -d "ip_address={{ inventory_hostname }}&hostname={{ varhostname.stdout }}&interface={{ interface }}&rslvalue={{ rslvalue }}" -X POST http://dev.trm.net:8088/ip_planning/rsl/postrsl -v
```

i want to post data with the same hostname but different interface and some other attributes.

This my curl command that i want :

```
curl -d "ip_address=IP_A&hostname=HOST_A&interface=IFACE_1&rslvalue=1,2,3,4,5" -X POST http://dev.trm.net:8088/ip_planning/rsl/postrsl -v

curl -d "ip_address=IP_A&hostname=HOST_A&interface=IFACE_2&rslvalue=5,4,3,2,1" -X POST http://dev.trm.net:8088/ip_planning/rsl/postrsl -v

curl -d "ip_address=IP_B&hostname=HOST_B&interface=IFACE_1&rslvalue=11,21,31,41,51" -X POST http://dev.trm.net:8088/ip_planning/rsl/postrsl -v
```

i'm tired a full-day, please help me. i've tried from my ansible script above but error

> "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined

Comment: For which task do you get this error

Comment: last task "post to DB via curl"

Comment: you have {{ item.interface.stdout }}in the task, but with_items is not present

Comment: How to use multiple with_items ? i want to use "item" variable with different value in "interface={{ item }}" and "rslvalue={{ item }}" curl command

Answer (score 0):

You have `{{ item.interface.stdout }}` in the last task, but with_items is not present.
Also when you use item in the shell command, use as  `"{{item}}"`

Comment: How to use multiple with_items ? i want to use "item" variable with different value in "interface={{ item }}" and "rslvalue={{ item }}" curl command

Comment: check out with_nested https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#nested-loops

Answer (score 0):

a little improvement make me small fun...

```
   - name: post to DB via curl
     shell: >
      curl -d "ip_address={{ inventory_hostname }}&hostname={{ varhostname.stdout }}&interface={{ item }}&rslvalue={{ item }}" -X POST http://dev.tr$
     with_items:
      - "{{ rslvalue.results | map(attribute='stdout') | list }}"
      - "{{ interface.results | map(attribute='stdout') | list }}"
```

but "item" variable always print "rslvalue" result. how to declare "item" with multiple with_items ??